# Pyspark dataframe shows error while displaying the dataframe contents

Tags: python, hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using spark 2.3.2 and using pyspark to read from the hive.
Here is my code;

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)
SparkContext.setSystemProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://17.20.24.186:9083").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
df=sql_sc.sql("SELECT * FROM mtsods.model_result_abt")
df.show() ## here is where error occurs
```

When ever i tried to display the contents of the dataframe an error occur as shown below,

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-1a6ce2362cd4> in <module>()
----> 1 df.show()

C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    348         """
    349         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 350             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    351         else:
    352             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o419.showString.
: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for HiveTableRelation `mtsods`.`model_result_abt`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [feature#319, profile_id#320, model_id#321, value#322, score#323, rank#324, year_d#325, taxpayer#326, it_ref_no#327]

    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2703)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Even df.count(), df.head(),df.first() shows the same error. How can I view the contents of the dataframe created?

Note: this same query works fine in hue(cloudera)--hive

Answer (score 0):

Its not because of show, or count operation. Spark work in lazy evaluation model. Hence you are facing error while apply any action operation.

Use before config while using spark submit

```
--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive
```

Comment: Exactly where i have to write this piece of code. Can you please guide me ?

Comment: I am using spyder IDE to code . @Rahul

Also i have updated the code above enabling hive support but still same error also i am not using spark-shell